# Android - Webview onPageFinished, still moves a bit after

Tags: android, webview

Not sure how to express that, but after a webview is loaded, after the `onPageFinished` has been called and the loader is removed, there remains a small "flash", a small period of time during which elements fit well into the webview or we see a small refresh.

Do you guys experience the same thing? I tried to implement all possible settings without any change in this behaviour.

I tried the `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the Manifest
I also tried to set webSettings like these

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here we have few several options. I think that `onPageFinished()` is triggered when all resources are downloaded, but they may not been already applied correctly, so the rendering phase is in progress. From Google docs :

> When onPageFinished() is called, the rendering picture may not be
>   updated yet.

They recommend to use [onNewPicture()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html#onNewPicture(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.graphics.Picture)) callback, but it is deprecated. You can try [onProgressChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged(android.webkit.WebView,%20int)) but obviously it won't help you much.
And of course you can extend WebView and override `invalidate()` :

```
@Override
public void invalidate() {
    super.invalidate();

    if (getContentHeight() > 0) {
        // WebView has displayed some content and is scrollable.
    }
}
```

But this stuff is also kind of tricky. Every non-trivial task with WebView is tricky. I don't think that rendering issue is really critical, especially if it happens less then after a second after `onPageFinished()` was triggered.

Comment: I will investigate this and let you know, thanks for the help